# Is a ridge beam necessary when doing plank framing for an A-Frame house?

Tags: framing

I am building a simple 30'W x 32'L A-frame lake cabin.  I will be using 2" x 6" Douglas Fir tongue and groove planks as the roof covering so that the inside walls of the A-frame can be natural wood.  I was planning on pre-fabbing the "A's".   If the purpose of the ridge beam is to keep the rafters from spreading, doesn't the use of plank vs studs negate this need?  My prefab will be a lot easier if I don't have deal with a ridge beam.  Its in the middle of nowhere so there are no building codes here but I do want the building as safe as possible.

Comment: I am confused. Looking at it from the front, the ridge beam is tying the left of the A frame to the right. How are the planks going to do that.

Comment: The purpose of a ridge beam is _not_ to keep rafters from spreading. Please clarify your design with details. If you don't use a ridge beam you must use rafter ties.

Comment: no insulation??

Comment: And let's distinguish between a ridge _beam_ and ridge _board_. The difference is crucial.

Comment: Jasen-Insulation consists of two layers of 1" rigid foam board over the waterproof membrane, which is placed on the  planks.  isherwood, the reason for the ridge board I used is the common reason given in a dozen internet articles I read.  -crp659 the planks are 2" thick, triple that of a sheet of plywood.  I'm buying it right from the sawmill and I do not intend to plane it much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many designs, a ridge beam is optional - sometimes reduced to a ridge board, sometimes deleted altogether.

In others, it's a weight-bearing member that keeps the peak from sinking and pushing the wall outward.

If this is a typical actual A-frame, the base can't spread because it's bolted to the foundation, and each pair of rafters is self-supporting (vertical load wise) while your planking (think of that as "very closely spaced purlins") will tie it together lengthways. If there's an upper floor with joists tying the rafters together, it's even more stable since that floor joist makes a nice stable triangle with the rafters.

If it's a steep roof with some vertical walls below, rather than an actual A-frame, you need to prevent it from spreading.

You MIGHT want some diagonal (galvanized) steel strapping on top of the roof boards for bracing. And you'll need to be on top of your temporary bracing when erecting the thing, as they will play dominoes (collapse long-ways) if given the opportunity before they are properly braced and tied together.

Comment: Thank you!  And yes, it is to be bolted directly to the foundation, on helical piers driven into bed rock. The A's are prefabbed using three 2"x8" laminated into to the uprights, then the base of the triangle is two  2" x 8" which then become the floor joists when the A is uprighted.

Comment: Are the three 2x8s close to the peak? How far down? One 2x8 in the same plane as the A-frame rafters sandwiched between the other two which overlap the rafters? Would the ridge board be attached to these 2x8 elements and used to carry lights, fans, other hanging elements?

Comment: The 2x8 are the rafters. 3 of them laminated together  30' long make up each section of the "A".  Each A has a bottom section that becomes the floor joist ,above it is another joist midway up to support the second floor. https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3a/93/8f/3a938f80bea460ceb70a284a22667f5b.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Having a ridge board simplifies construction,  the unclad frame will be self supporting, the framing can be squared up and and bracing straps can applied onto the rafters and tensioned before the rafters are planked.

Yes, it's a waste of wood as the planking can probably carry that load instead, but it's common to waste wood in framing when it simplifies the work.

If you put the strapping on the planked surface there's a risk that it intefere with your roof cladding.